# React-query: looping through useMutation can only retrieve the last request data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-query

looping through an array and doing a mutation on each item

```
  array?.forEach((item, index) => {
        mutate(
            {
                          ...item
            },
            {
               onSuccess: ({ id }) => {
                 console.log(id)
               },
            }
        );
    });
```

the network request is working fine, but I can only retrieve the last request id.
is it possible that the onSuccess is overriding each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onSuccess` callback of `useMutation`. The callbacks on `mutate` work slightly differently:

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations#mutation-side-effects
- https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#some-callbacks-might-not-fire